# Twitter GetFollowers() returning 0 followers

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I am using TweetInvi C# twitter library to make twitter API calls. I have a list of Twitter users and I want to get just 20 followers of each of these users in my list. I execute `User.GetFollowers(20)` in a loop. I sometimes do get followers but sometimes get 0 followers. I checked the actual user on Twitter and the user has lots of followers (~ 1500).

I am handling rate limit. I have `Thread.Sleep(queryRateLimits.ResetDateTimeInMilliseconds)` in `TweetinviEvents_QueryBeforeExecute` event.

**Edit:** Adding my code:

```
using Tweetinvi;
using Tweetinvi.Core;
using Tweetinvi.Core.Credentials;
using Tweetinvi.Core.Interfaces;

. . . . . . . . .    
    foreach (string influencerScreenName in screenNames)
    {
        var _influencer = User.GetUserFromScreenName(influencerScreenName);
        var followers = _influencer.GetFollowers(50).ToList();
        ...
    }
```

The get followers method returns 0 followers sporadically, even though the actual user has lot of followers (confirmed while debugging)

Can you please suggest some workarounds or point any mistake in my approach,

Comment: Maybe your target user is just really unpopular?

Comment: Not really! The user has lots of followers, Minimum 300 to max 3000...

Comment: It would help to see the code you're using.

Comment: Code explains error the best. If you could provide it will be best.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited my post and added relevant code.

Comment: Hello, can you please provide the username/id of the user for who you encounter this issue.